# Label of CTA for starting an online interview

Tags: interaction-design, ux-writing

In order to start a Video Interview, the user needs to click an action button. What could be a clear and self-explanatory label for such a CTA?

How about **Start Answering**? Wondering if it is intuitive enough

Comment: A video interview? Can you give more context about the situation? I think you mean a video interview with human resources to get a job right? Which questions are you going to make?

Comment: Yep, you got it

Comment: Please let us know, what you decided to conclude

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by a **Video Interview**. However, *Start Answering* might not be the best label for something that isn't clearly defined as a test.

If it is a video call where people get interviewed, I'd suggest going with **Answer Call** or if it questionnaire-based call,  **Begin Interview** might make sense as well

Answer (score 1):

I don't think "start answering" is good choice cause in that case answers can be by texting so there is a confusion here. I prefer to have a clear call to action, may be "start the video interview"  would be better.
Just try to set the main action that the users will take, you can do a test after that with anyone setting beside you to get more insight.

Answer (score 1):

CTA in every as well as your case highly depends on the business model of your application. It also depends who are the product best for

1. Organizations of any size who want to hire the best talent
2. Academic programs and schools at institutions worldwide who want to identify their best-fit applicants
3. Growing Startups and Scaleups
4. More than 5,000 customers spanning across all industries and company size demographics.

Then you can choose from these or something similar to these:

- **Request a demo**
- **Get Started Now**
- **Sign Up - Its Free**
- **Start a Free Trial**

Please dont use **Start Interviewing**

Check these links:
https://www.skeeled.com/video-interview

https://www.jobsoid.com/

https://www.sparkhire.com/

https://talview.com/video-interviewing/

https://easyhire.me/

https://www.montagetalent.com/

https://www.recright.com/en/

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it depends, I don't believe anyone here would be able to give you a based answer whether or not your users(!) would be able to comprehend the text let alone if it will motivate them to action.

"start answering" is fine, But from my experience, it is usually best to focus on the outcome of the action when deciding on a label. In this case, it seems that the interview will start after clicking this button. Perhaps a more suitable label then could be **"start interview"** (it aligns the user's expectations, and is more concise) other elements of the page can also determine what label is fitting for example: a large title stating: "Ready to get started?" then the call to action can be "yes, take me to your interviewer" or whatever tone of voice that fits your brand..

potentially presenting personal value/impact would have better impact. If users are paid perhaps a more suitable label could be **"5 minutes of your time, earn 20$"**

Other considerations for text supporting the call to action in this page should address users fears, and setting expectations, for example: *"how long will this take?" "Can I stop whenever I want?" "what type of questions will I be asked?"*

In short, there is no one size fits all here and no one could tell you better than your users what works for them. So why not just test it?

Good article describing different ways to test your microcopy: [Testing for UX writers: know when your words are working](https://uxdesign.cc/testing-for-ux-writers-78158531179f)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion: "Join Interview".

It gives the user a sense of joining to a session/meeting, something formal/business casual.